# How can I find files that don't contain specific metadata?

Tags: itunes, music, metadata

I recently discovered that a currently-unknown number of files on in my music collection have been corrupted or otherwise damaged. These files do not play in the Apple Music app, even though they look fine there-- there's no outward indication of a problem. So far, the only difference I can find between the corrupted files and normal ones, is that the metadata (Artist, Title, etc.) for the bad files isn't showing up in Finder like it does for files that work. The metadata is still showing up in Music.

Since I don't know how many files are affected-- I initially spotted this with a single file, but now more have popped up-- I was wondering if there was a way to use either Finder or the terminal to locate all the files in my broader music folder that do not contain the metadata that is missing on these "bad" files. Fixing these files is a different story, but at least I can figure out the scope of the problem.

I'm currently running the latest version of MacOSX (11.6). Here's what a "good" versus a "bad" version of this metadata looks like:
[image: Screenshot of metadata from a working file.] [image: Screenshot of metadata from a bad file.]

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? Please provide a screenshot of a clear cut example of a good file vs. a bad file  where you are seeing/not seeing this information.

Comment: Provided above.